# jQuery UI portlets

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make panels which are draggable, resizable, collapsible, closable and can be maximised and minimized as well as follows.

I also want a scroll for the portlet content, if resizing overflows the content.
When I set `overflow:auto` the scroll comes even if the content is not overflowing.

```
.portlet {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```

you can have look over my code and demo here [panel code](http://jsfiddle.net/jJJW7/70/)
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your design is fluid design so it change on resizing the size of browser ...and for that there is no need to use scroll bar

Comment: its not a fluid design..i have not used media queries or any such responsive feature

Answer (score 1):

I dug around and found this Tutorial-[Create a Windows-like Interface with jQuery UI](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-windows-like-interface-with-jquery-ui/)

here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/UXmRA/) and the code-

```
  var _init = $.ui.dialog.prototype._init;
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._init = function() {
        _init.apply(this, arguments);

        var dialog_element = this;
        var dialog_id = this.uiDialogTitlebar.next().attr('id');

        this.uiDialogTitlebar.append('<a href="#" id="' + dialog_id + 
        '-minbutton" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-minimize ui-corner-all">'+
        '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span></a>');

        $('#dialog_window_minimized_container').append(
            '<div class="dialog_window_minimized ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" id="' + 
            dialog_id + '_minimized">' + this.uiDialogTitlebar.find('.ui-dialog-title').text() + 
            '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-newwin"></div>');

        $('#' + dialog_id + '-minbutton').hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
        }, function() {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        }).click(function() {
            dialog_element.close();
            $('#' + dialog_id + '_minimized').show();
        });

        $('#' + dialog_id + '_minimized').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            dialog_element.open();
        });
    };

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#create_button').button().click(function() {
                var create_dialog = $('#dialog_window_1');
                var create_button = $(this);
                if( create_dialog.dialog('isOpen') ) {
                    create_button.button('option', 'label', 'Create a new Window');
                    create_dialog.dialog('close');
                } else {
                    create_button.button('option', 'label', 'Close Window');
                    create_dialog.dialog('open');
                }
            });

            $('#dialog_window_1').dialog({
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                autoOpen : false,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        text: 'Create',
                        click: function() {
                            var div_count = $('.dialog_window').length + 1;
                            var div_id = 'dialog_window_' + div_count;
                            var div_title = $('#new_window_title').val();
                            var div_content = $('#new_window_content').val();
                            var buttons = new Array();
                            if( $('#alertbutton').is(':checked') ) {
                                buttons.push({
                                    text: 'ALERT',
                                    click: function() {
                                        alert('ALERTING from Dialog Widnow: ' + div_title);
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            if( $('#closebutton').is(':checked') ) {
                                buttons.push({
                                    text: 'CLOSE',
                                    click: function() {
                                        $('#' + div_id).dialog('close');
                                    }
                                });
                            }

                            $('body').append('<div class="dialog_window" id="' + div_id + '">' + div_content + '</div>');

                            var dialog = $('#' + div_id).dialog({
                                width: 'auto',
                                height: 'auto',
                                title : div_title,
                                autoOpen : true,
                                buttons: buttons
                            });
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            $('#buttonlist').buttonset();
        });`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your css code to the following.

```
.portlet {
    position: absolute;
}
.portlet-content {
    overflow:auto !important;
}
```

Comment: did the changes...still not working..demo is here [panel demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jJJW7/72/) @Doehl

Answer (score 0):

The thing that is causing the scrollbars in your jsFiddle is the `ui-resizable-handle` elements.

Adding these CSS statements should remove the scrollbars until they are needed and doesn't seem to affect the drag handle's functionality

```
.ui-resizable-s { bottom: 0 !important }
.ui-resizable-e { right: 0 !important }
```

Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJJW7/95/)

As an aside. Although they seem to behave better if you remove the jquery stylesheet link you had in the jsFiddle HTML area, removing it alters their starting positions. So I've left it in with the expectation that it works correctly for you in your actual code.